# Is Gower's Distance a metric?

Tags: statistics, metric-spaces, hausdorff-distance, mixing-variables

A novice here

My previous question was closed due to inadequate details

So here I've added more details

A metric should basically satisfy 3 properties

1. Distance is equal to zero if and only if $x$ is equal to $y$ ($d(x,y)=0 ⇔ x=y$))
2. Distance from $x$ to $y$ is the same as distance from $y$ to $x$ ($d(x,y)=d(y,x)$)
3. Distance should satisfy the triangular inequality ($d(x,y)\leq d(x,z) +d(z,y)$)

I already know that Gower's distance satisfy the first 2 properties to be a metric, but I want to know whether it satisfies the triangular inequality property.

The reason I want to know this, is because all metric spaces are Hausdorff spaces, and I want use the Gowers distance in order to find the Hausdorff distance for 2 sets of points.

In my case, a point contains data of mixed types (logical, categorical & numeral), and therefore I have to use the Gowers distance.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Edit:

According to a suggestion on the comments, here is the formal definition of a metric

A metric on a set X is a function (called the distance function or simply distance)

$d : X × X → R$

(where R is the set of real numbers). For all $ x, y, z $ in $X$, this function is required to satisfy the following conditions:

1. $d(x, y) ≥ 0$ (non-negativity)
2. $d(x, y) = 0$   if and only if   $x = y $
3. $d(x, y) = d(y, x) $    (symmetry)
4. $d(x, z) ≤ d(x, y) + d(y, z) $

Note that the first condition is implied by the others.

Comment: For people who don't know it, Gower's original paper can be found [here](http://members.cbio.mines-paristech.fr/~jvert/svn/bibli/local/Gower1971general.pdf).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please add the definitoon of the metric in the post.

Comment: @ArcticChar added the formal definition of a metric

Comment: I am sorry, i mean the Gower metric.

Comment: @ArcticChar the paper has been linked to, in the first comment

Comment: The paper has 14 pages. You have more chances to get an answer if you extract the definition of Gower's distance and copy it in your question.

Comment: By the way, have you read the paper? It seems to me that it mentions the triangle inequality in Equation (4).

Comment: @Miguel yeah I did, but I could not properly understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the answer in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15287/hierarchical-clustering-with-mixed-type-data-what-distance-similarity-to-use

> "**Gower distance**". Without ordinal variables present (i.e. w/o using the Podani's option) $\sqrt{1-GS}$ behaves as Euclidean distance, it fully supports euclidean space. But $1-GS$ is only a metric (supports triangular inequality), not Euclidean. With ordinal variables present (using the Podani's option) $\sqrt{1-GS}$ is only a metric, not Euclidean; and $1-GS$ isn't a metric at all. [See also](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22213/3277).

Therefore it can be used a metric

---

Papers

1 Gower J. C. A general coefficient of similarity and some of its properties // Biometrics, 1971, 27, 857-872

2 Podani, J. Extending Gower’s general coefficient of similarity to ordinal characters // Taxon, 1999, 48, 331-340